# quitar direccion de carpeta en link

Tags: php, html

Necesito quitar la direccion de la carpeta en el link.
Conseguí quitar la extension (.php) creando un archivo htacess en la carpeta principal, logrando quitar el .html de la pagina principal, pero tengo un archivo .php que necesito borrarle el .php

Como lo tengo: www.mipagina/pages/contacto.php

Como quiero dejarlo: www.mipagina/contacto

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? No quiero quitar el archivo de la carpeta /pages para que este todo más ordenado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta rule de .htaccess (entiendo que usas rewrite, sinó deberás activarlo antes con `RewriteEngine on`):

```
RewriteRule ^contacto$ pages/contacto.php
```

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.